# Cual es la diferencia entre --force y --force-with-lease en git?

Tags: git, git-push

En git al hacer un `push` si las ramas local y remota no concuerdan es necesario hacer un `force push` (aunque no sea bien visto hacer un `force push`). En git hay dos opciones para esto la opción `--force` y la opción `--force-with-lease`.

Por el nombre parece que `--force-with-lease` es menos agresivo o no siempre hace el push pero quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre estas dos opciones.

Ej: `git push origin master --foce` vs `git push origin master --force-with-lease`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git push `--force` es destructiva porque incondicionalmente sobrescribe el repositorio remoto con lo que tenga a nivel local, posiblemente sobrescribir cualquier cambio que un miembro del equipo ha empujado, lo cual puedes borrar los cambios de algún miembro. Sin embargo hay una manera mejor la opción  `--force-with-lease` la cual es la mejor recomendada puede ayudar cuando se necesita hacer un empuje forzado pero todavía asegurarse de no sobrescribir el trabajo de otros.

Comment: +1 excelente respuesta!